# 3d trajectory path calculation

Tags: c, 3d

I am developing a soccer game where user has to select velocity, angle,azimuth so that user can post a goal using the desired selection.Can anybody formulate me as how to create a trajectory path for the game.Please help me as I am unable to find the solution.

Comment: That link gets me a big old 404.

Comment: Are you handling lift, drag, spin, wind, *etc*?  If not, and you simply want a trajectory based on initial velocity, direction and gravity, you can calculate it precisely with a parabola.  Otherwise it's best to calculate the curve in a series of small and discrete steps (or involve yourself in hideous integrals).

Comment: @paddy :No I am not using any of those kind.Could you please formulate  me with sample if possible.

Comment: @CodeMonkey: Was runnino but few min ago but it is not running now.Dont know why.Check some time later.

Comment: @user1512727 it's still not working...

Comment: @Code Monkey: It is working now.can check it \

Comment: @user1512727 that so ain't working.

Answer (score 6):

It's basic physics.  Assuming Z is up, your initial X- and Y-velocities are constant, and determined by the initial angle (using trig).  The Z component is entirely determined by gravity.  You take the elevation angle and (again, using trig) convert it to a component.  That is your initial Z-velocity.

This is the simplest formulation, which ignores wind, spin and drag (*ie* the ball does not move laterally during flight and is affected only by gravity).

```
vx = power * cos(elevation) * sin(azimuth);
vy = power * cos(elevation) * cos(azimuth);
vz = power * sin(elevation);
```

Now, the position at time `t` is simple Newtonian physics:

```
x = vx * t;
y = vy * t;
z = vz * t - 0.5 * g * t * t;
```

Where `g` is gravity (9.81 m/s/s)

But using these formulae directly doesn't let you calculate bounces etc.  For that you need to compute it stepwise.  That means, for small time increments (`dt`) you take your current position and velocity and modify them.

```
vx;             // unchanged
vy;             // unchanged
vz -= g * dt;   // gravity
x += vx * dt;
y += vy * dt;
z += vz * dt;
```

If your Z-position goes below the ground, you negate `vz` to allow the bounce.  You do similar reflections if you hit a surface (reflect the vector against the surface normal).

Things are trickier if you want the flight to be affected by spin (Magnus effect) and other forces.  You may also want to damp your reflections because energy is lost whenever the ball bounces.

That's up to you.  I've given the basics, and I hope that helps.

You should read up on projectile motion.  Once you get something basic working and want to make the motion more realistic, read up on aerodynamics / fluid dynamics of sports balls...  Pretty much any book or article by Rabindra Mehta would be a good starting point.